# How to merge 2D arrays along rows in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, merge, 2d

I have two 2D numpy arrays and I want to add one to the end of other.

```
Example:
```

`

```
My arrays are a & b:
a = [[ 1 , 2],
     [ 2 , 4],
     [ 6 , 8]]
b = [[ 3 , 5],
     [ 7 , 4]]
The result will be:
C = [[ 1 , 2],
     [ 2 , 4],
     [ 6 , 8],
     [ 3 , 5],
     [ 7 , 4]]
```

`

Comment: using python 'extend' is an option for you --> https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_extend.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.concatenate()`:

```
c = np.concatenate((a, b), axis=0)
```

Comment: note: this returns a ndarray, so cast back to a list if that isn't wanted

Comment: I am happy to help :)